# Running NUnit summary after completion of NUnit tests in a batch file

Tags: vb.net, nunit, watin

I want to to run [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) summary.exe after successful completion of a NUnit Tests assembly. I am calling NUnit from a batch file and then I want to call NUnit summary. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just add nunit summary.exe after the call to nunit.console.exe in your batch file. If you want more control than that you should checkout Powershell which would make it much easier to check if the results.xml file exists after your test run.